# How to Horizontally center Text Div with position absolute and left offset

Tags: html, css

How can I center align text in a div with the following structure:

```css
.centerText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerText">Hello World</div>
```

Doing so still aligns the text to the left side; 100px from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the text centered while still using `left: 100px` you need to add `right: 100px` to automatically set the width of your div and have the same amount of spacing on both sides therefore centring the div too.

```css
.centerText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerText">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: When the value becomes greater than 50% of the parent width. It no longer works

Comment: It does not mean that it yields the same result as your code but.  And which value becomes greater than 50% of the parent width? can you please also include the parent div in your question too than?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.centerText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centerText">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Well i need to use the left: 100px property as it dynamically changes

Answer (score 0):

to center a text or an element inside a `div` it has to have a larger width,

take a look at : `calc()` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

you can set the width of the `div` according to the page ( dynamically ) and remove the `100px` from the left ( and another `100px` from the right ) so the div will be centered and the `text` too ( with `text-align:center` )

```css
.centerText {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: red;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="centerText">Hello World</div>
```